# When wrapping IconButton with a container it doesn't contain the entire icon, & I have to press on the container in particular so the onPressed works

Tags: flutter, android-alertdialog, flutter-getx, iconbutton

In the following code and as shown in photo, the container wrapping the IconButton doesn't contain the icon, and for the dialog to be closed I have to click on the container (blue area) but when clicking the icon nothing happens.. what's the problem and how to fix it? thanks already!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LyIEJ.jpg)

```
              Get.dialog(
                Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: Container(
                    width: screenWidth(1.15),
                    height: screenHeight(1.7),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: AppColors.mainWhiteColor,
                      borderRadius:
                          BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(screenWidth(70))),
                      border: Border.all(
                        color: AppColors.mainDarkPurple,
                        width: screenWidth(170),
                      ),
                    ),
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Align(
                          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                          child: Material(
                            child: Container(
                              width: screenWidth(40),
                              height: screenWidth(40),
                              color: AppColors.mainBlueColor,
                              child: IconButton(
                                onPressed: () => Get.back(),
                                icon: Icon(
                                  Icons.close,
                                  size: screenWidth(18),
                                  color: AppColors.mainBlackColor,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        SvgPicture.asset(
                          'assets/images/pop-up.svg',
                          width: screenWidth(4),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: screenWidth(30),
                        ),
                        Material(
                          child: CustomTextField(
                            hitText: "ارسل شكوى/ مقترح",
                            controller: feedBackNameController,
                            hintColor: Colors.grey,
                            fillColor: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.1),
                            startPadding: screenWidth(40),
                            endPadding: screenWidth(40),
                            maxline: 8,
                            maxlength: 500,
                            bottomPadding: screenWidth(40),
                          ),
                        ),
                        CustomButton(
                          textSize: screenWidth(25),
                          text: "ارسل",
                          textColor: AppColors.mainWhiteColor,
                          backgroundColor: AppColors.mainDarkPurple,
                          width: screenWidth(1.5),
                          hight: screenWidth(10),
                          onPressed: () {},
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              );
```

I tried SizedBox and BoxConstrainsts, same results and I can't keep the icon with its default size it's bigger than I need.. I also tried to wrap Material with that container instead of wrapping the icon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using **FittedBox** to make the *IconButton* **fit** with the *Container*.

just ***wrap your IconButton inside FittedBox*** so the IconButton will fit the size to your Container

**remove the size inside Icon** because it will just fit with the Container size

```
Container(
   width: screenWidth(40),
   height: screenWidth(40),
   color: AppColors.mainBlueColor,
   child: FittedBox(
        child: IconButton(
            onPressed: () => Get.back(),
            icon: Icon(
                Icons.close,
                color: AppColors.mainBlackColor,
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

**`IconButton`** Widget has property called **`iconSize`**, you need to it instead of size property inside **`Icon`** widget

````
                Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: Container(
                    width: screenWidth(1.15),
                    height: screenHeight(1.7),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: AppColors.mainWhiteColor,
                      borderRadius:
                          BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(screenWidth(70))),
                      border: Border.all(
                        color: AppColors.mainDarkPurple,
                        width: screenWidth(170),
                      ),
                    ),
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Align(
                          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                          child: Material(
                            child: Container(
                              width: screenWidth(40),
                              height: screenWidth(40),
                              color: AppColors.mainBlueColor,
                              child: IconButton(
                                iconSize: screenWidth(18), // ADD IT HERE
                                onPressed: () => Get.back(),
                                icon: Icon(
                                  Icons.close,
                                  // DELETE SIZE FROM HERE
                                  color: AppColors.mainBlackColor,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        SvgPicture.asset(
                          'assets/images/pop-up.svg',
                          width: screenWidth(4),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: screenWidth(30),
                        ),
                        Material(
                          child: CustomTextField(
                            hitText: "ارسل شكوى/ مقترح",
                            controller: feedBackNameController,
                            hintColor: Colors.grey,
                            fillColor: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.1),
                            startPadding: screenWidth(40),
                            endPadding: screenWidth(40),
                            maxline: 8,
                            maxlength: 500,
                            bottomPadding: screenWidth(40),
                          ),
                        ),
                        CustomButton(
                          textSize: screenWidth(25),
                          text: "ارسل",
                          textColor: AppColors.mainWhiteColor,
                          backgroundColor: AppColors.mainDarkPurple,
                          width: screenWidth(1.5),
                          hight: screenWidth(10),
                          onPressed: () {},
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              );```
````